# Symfony2 / SonataAdminBundle / Sending email after editing record

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I need to send an email based on template after I edited a record using SonataAdminBundle.

In normal site I sending email in controller. Something like this:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setSubject('Subject')
        ->setFrom('from@site.com')
        ->setTo($member->getEmail())
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'AcmeSiteBundle:Site:email.html.twig',
                array('name' => $member->getFirstName())
            )
        )
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

But in admin I configure *configureFormFields*, *preUpdate*, *postUpdate* methods of *MyAdmin* which extended from *Admin*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the solution is: use EventListener.

Create file *AdminApplicationListener.php* in *VendorName/SiteBundle/EventListener* with this code:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\SiteBundle\EventListener;

class AdminApplicationListener
{
    /**
     *
     * @var Swift_Mailer
     */
    private $__mailer = null;
    private $__templating = null;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, $templating)
    {
        $this->__mailer = $mailer;
        $this->__templating = $templating;
    }

    public function onApplication( \Sonata\AdminBundle\Event\PersistenceEvent $event )
    {       
        $ac = $event->getObject();

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setContentType('text/html')
            ->setSubject('[VendorName] Object was edited')
            ->setFrom('admin@VendorName.ru')
            ->setTo($ac->getEmail())
            ->setBody(
                $this->__templating->render(
                    'VendorNameSiteBundle:Admin:email.html.twig',
                    array('name' => $ac->getFirstName())
                )
            )
        ;
        $this->__mailer->send($message);

    }
}
```

In *VendorName/SiteBundle/Resources/config/services.yml* add this:

```
services:
    vendor_name.admin.on_application:
        class: VendorName\SiteBundle\EventListener\AdminApplicationListener
        arguments:
            mailer: @mailer
            templating: @templating
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sonata.admin.event.persistence.post_update, method: onApplication }
```

I think that it's not best practice but for first step to it it's ok :)